# Posting data in ruby

Tags: ruby, http-post

I am new in ruby and I have not got much experience with posting datas over web-servers.
I need to POST some data to a webservice written in asp .net.
The url is like:

`http://localhost:8080/TheService.asmx/CollectData`

I've tried to post using TCPSocket and RestClient but I couldn't.

Can anyone give me any solution?

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-i-post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need Net::HTTP class.

First you need to create valid URI:

```
require 'uri'
uri = URI.parse('http://localhost:8080')
```

Then create new `Net::HTTP` object

```
require 'net/http'
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
```

From now on you can send requests using methods like `get` and `post`. To send a hash simply do:

```
 http.post('/TheService.asmx/CollectData', {hash: 'data', foo: 'bar'}.to_query)
```

Comment: I never used this *lib*. Thus asking - why do we need the line `{hash: 'data', foo: 'bar'}.to_query` ?

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I get the response from the server after posting?

Comment: @ChcapicSz - `post` method returns response, so just assign it to something `reponse = http.post(...)`

Comment: @ArupRakshit - this line contains all the date which will be send with a post request, obviously its content depends on a service you're calling. We need to call to_query, to format it into a query string. See the link in a comment under a question.